# How to start wuala on the linux commandline with auto login

Tags: linux, command-line, wuala

When i start wuala on the linux commandline like this, it logs me in and the folder is mounted:

> wualamcd login username password enableAutoLogin

I can shut it down from another console typing

> wuala shutdown

But how do I actually use the auto login that I just set using the enableAutoLogin
switch? What is the command to start it again, so it logs in but does not need the password? I tried

> wualamcd login

and wuala starts but no one gets logged in.

Auto login in gui mode works fine. This is 32 bit linux with openjdk 6 JRE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work the way you want it to according to the wuala forums.

The enableAutoLogin feature is a setting for the gui, not the CLI. 
The bigger issue is when you start the server that way, your login/pass is now visible via ps -ef and history.

An interesting solution would perhaps be a cron job coupled with the following bash script, taken from the wuala forum post [here](https://forum.wuala.com/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1097&sid=91d17dd96a206e3f404a7a44193caa37&start=10). This would give you some granularity on when it's on, and automatically restart it if it is shut down.

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME=   # The name of the process owner running Wuala
USER=    # The name of your Wuala User
PASS=    # your password
### Touch this and make +rw for $NAME
LOGFILE="/var/log/wuala.log"
WUALATEST=`ps -U $NAME -u $NAME u | grep -q [w]ualacmd ; echo $?`

function wualastart {
        wualacmd &>> $LOGFILE &
        sleep 10
        wualacmd login $USER $PASS &>> $LOGFILE
        if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        echo -e "\n Wuala Started Successfully \n"
        fi
}

function wualafinal {
  if [ $WUALATEST == 1 ]
    then
        wualastart
    else
        echo -e "\n Can't start Wuala, It's already running \n"
  fi
}

until wualafinal; do
  echo "Wuala is restarting -- Code: $?.
        Trying to Respawn... " >&2
  sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

`wualacmd login <myuser> <mypassword> enableAutoLogin`

Comment: That's exactly what the question says, now he wants to automatically log in after shutting it down, without typing that all in again.

Comment: oops, then its impossible.